# OpenGL (ES) -- is scaling computed by the CPU or the GPU, and is it an 'expensive' operation (relatively speaking)?

Tags: android, graphics, opengl-es

The reason I ask is that I've written a rendering scheme for a 2d top down game that uses ortho projection. To give the appearance of depth I scale the objects. I'm wondering if switching to frustum and using the z-coor in lieu of scaling will improve performance. I would just implement it and find out, but it would take me several hours, and its easier to just ask here.

Comment: What kind of 'scaling' operation are you doing. Could you post some example code?

Comment: I think he is talking generally.

Comment: A scale on a primitive shape (circle) w/o textures using gl.glScalef(w,h,y).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`glScale` just simply modifies the matrix on top of the stack, all done in CPU. As for expensive "relatively speaking", I guess I ask - relative to what? :) It's not that expensive if you are doing it occasionally. If you are doing it in a critical inner loop, then, yeah, it could be expensive.

Comment: I'm scaling about 100 times per frame. So I guess I should take a stab at frustrum?

Comment: Do you mean a perspective projection? I don't see 100 times per frame being that big of a deal if you are talking about a sprite-baesd game. However, you should use a profiler to see if glScale even shows up on the hit list.

Comment: Good call. Yeah its not even making a dent. 3.5% of rendering time, which is about 40% of total program time. 3 hours of refactoring to get 1-2 frame rate increase. nah.

Answer (score 1):

Almost certainly faster to switch to a 3D view and use `glFrustum`. It's what the hardware is really built for, and it does it *quite* well, at least in most cases.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware, glScale http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glScale.xml, is a standard OpenGL function, which modifies the matrix, but it does not specify if it is done on the CPU or the GPU. My guess is this would vary by implementation, but it could be done on the GPU; or the CPU, like any other OpenGL function.

Comment: I would recommend using something other than glScale, because it messes with the lighting "If scale factors other than 1 are applied to the modelview matrix and lighting is enabled, lighting often appears wrong. In that case, enable automatic normalization of normals by calling glEnable with the argument GL_NORMALIZE."

Answer (score 1):

2D using an ortho projection won't scale on z-depth change. If you're wondering cost relative to changing the z-depth it *should* be an identical cost - just a matrix transform, but might look different, and might interfere with clipping planes. Making a function call is always more expensive than *not* making a function call, however, so if you can track and use depth at the same time, it should be micro-cheaper, with previously listed caveats. Hope that's not too much word soup.